# Not refresh after submit in Yii

Tags: yii, form-submit, page-refresh

Is there a way in Yii to stop refreshing the page after a submit button. I want the user to keep the content after he/she submits the form.

Any help/advise will be appreciated.

Comment: are you looking for Ajax (with Javascript)?

Comment: @Shadow_boi Yes. That could be a solution. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

it requires quite a bit of coding, and we can't really help since we don't know where you are at. i believe you can get some tutorials on google. You should give it a try and make a post again if you are stuck at something.

here are some links that i found:
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/8219-solved-ajax-form-submission/ 
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/49/update-content-in-ajax-with-partialrender